# Reading a file from Scanner but it won't print

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a class that reads a section of a txt file. The code works for some people but to me it won't print to console or attach to my JTextArea(my ultimate goal)

I just want to find out if its the code or the file that is the issue.

```
 public void readFiles(String fileString)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    file = new File(fileString);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String line = "";

    // access file
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        return; // don't continue if the file is not found
    }

    // if more lines in file, go to next line
    Boolean started = false;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("BGEND")) {
            started = false;

        }

        if (started) // tag in the txt to locate position
        {

            System.out.println(line);//won't print on my console
            lb1.setText(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.
            window2.add(lb1); //adds to JPanel
        }

        if (line.equals("BGSTART")) {
            started = true;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

This is my file

```
BGSTART   
Ashley the principal at Leicester,
Memorial School has been given the
task of matching some students names
to their bus numbers and departure
time, after their computer system went 
down. Using only the clues that follow, 
match each student to their bus number 
and route to determine who goes where 
and when!
Remember, as with all grid-based logic 
puzzles, no option in any category will 
ever be used more than once. If you get 
stuck or run into a problem try the Clear 
button to remove any mistakes that might 
be present on the grid, or use one of your 
4 hints with the Hint button to see what is 
the next logical step to solve the puzzle.
BGEND
```

Comment: You don't even need BGSTART and BGEND to begin with. Is there are reason why you are using these?

Comment: Oh sorry.Yes cause that is only part of the file. It contains other lines that  needs to be used somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know if you pasted poorly, but there are trailing spaces after BGSTART \*in your file\* so it won't match your `.equals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Boolean started = false;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {

    line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("BGSTART")) {
        started = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (line.startsWith("BGEND")) {
        started = false;
        break;
    }

    if (started) // tag in the txt to locate position
    {
        System.out.println(line);//won't print on my console
        lb1.setText(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.
        window2.add(lb1); //adds to JPanel
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

Try this.  Basically, if you have something like:

```
some lines of text here
BGSTART
some lines of text here
BGEND
```

The code should skip the lines of text preceding the BGSTART marking. Once this marker is encountered, the boolean flag value changes to TRUE to let the code know you started reading valid lines, and immediately skip the rest of the code to get the next line. If the BGEND marker is encountered, it signifies the end. So in this case, you want to break completely out of the loop. Then, if the boolean flag is set to TRUE, you want to do something with the line of text read from the file.

I think the above code does exactly what you need.  It should also work for a case like this:

```
some lines of text here
BGSTART
some lines of text here
BGEND
some lines of text here
BGSTART
some lines of text here
BGEND
```

Effectively reading only those lines of text between BGSTART and BGEND, and not those between BGEND and BGSTART.

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("BGSTART")) {
            started = true;
        }

        if (line.equals("BGEND")) {
            started = false;

        }
        if (started) // tag in the txt to locate position
        {

            System.out.println(line);//won't print on my console
            lb1.setText(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.
            window2.add(lb1); //adds to JPanel
        }

    }
```

This way the program checks first if the first line equals to the "BGSTART" string, sets the boolean to true and will continue to the next if statement and execute that code as long as it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: This is exactly what OP has, but your code will print BGSTART now, which idt is what OP wants.

Comment: Its not exactly what the OP has, in the OP's code the boolean will always be false because when the first line - BGSTART is tested against if its equal to BGEND, the code in the if statement wont be fired, instead it goes to the second if statement and skips that too because started is still false. Then in the last if statement the boolean is set to true, but that doesn't matter anymore. Then the next line is processed and that won't match the first if statement either. etc etc.

Comment: all the way untill it reaches the line BGEND and that will set the boolean to false (which it already is) and nothing gets printed. Unlike my code that prints all the lines from start to end.

Comment: You don't need to print BGSTART.  Once BGSTART is found, the boolean is set to true. Then the when the next line is read it will be printed.  It will continue to print lines until BGEND is found. State is retained because \*the boolean\* is declared outside the loop, so it will remain true until BGEND is found.

Comment: I don't know what code you are reading, but at the top is the code the OP posted, that will check if the line BGSTART equals BGEND which it will not and the boolean remains false, so it will print nothing because the second if statement checks if the boolean is true, which its not.

Comment: Run your code and run OPs (make sure you get rid of the trailing whitespace on the first line of his text file).  When you get confused about why OPs code works: first line=BGSTART, BGSTART != BGEND, started = false (no print), BGSTART=BGSTART -> started = true.  Next line != BGEND, started is still true, print line. Etc, etc, last line=BGEND, started = false, end function.

Comment: Well if the code works then why did the OP start this topic if he says that his program won't print out anything...

Comment: OP didn't account for trailing whitespace.  Since line is the full line, if there is anything after BGSTART on the same line, it won't match the `.equals()` and then `started` will never be set to true.

Comment: I removed that whitespace after i adjusted my own code, my mistake. I ran the OP's code with the whitespace and it didnt work.